# Rspec: be_succes(not be_success) passes

Tags: rspec, rspec3

I noticed in one of my tests that I had a typo for the response check, `expect(response).to be_succes` instead of `expect(response).to be_success`. The test passed. Why did the test still pass?

`response.succes?` returns:

```
Failure/Error: response.succes?
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `succes?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007fe6e22a2530>
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Can you paste the rspec file?

Comment: Maybe make more obvious typo like `be_sssss` and see

Comment: @aBadAssCowboy I did, I tried be_succe and be_successssss and they both failed. The file, including the file name, is fine. I have also tested this in other files in my app and it also passes on be_succes. Thanks.

Comment: is it `to be_succes` or `not_to be_succes` ??

Comment: to be_succes in this case but I tried not_to be_succes and that also passes.

Comment: Can you check if the `response` object responds to the `succes?` method. Like `response.succes?` or `response.succes` ?

Comment: I get an error for response.succes?: Failure/Error: response.succes?
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `succes?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007fe6e22a2530>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118421/discussion-between-adrian-mann-and-abadasscowboy).

Comment: Have you tried writing `response.success?`

Comment: @RaVeN Yes, this is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a [chat](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1681) with the guys at RSpec about this issue and it turns out that this is a somewhat intentional operation and is due to the `present_tense_predicate` and `predicate` methods in RSpec: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/be.rb#L248.

As a result of raising this issue, it has been proposed that this issue wil be removed in RSpec 4: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/935.

Comment: @PaulFioravanti Just had to wait a bit.